# Undock a dialog (make it floating)

Tags: inkscape

I have no problem with docking a floating dialog (by dragging its tab to the left or to the right side of the document window or at / near of another docked dialog).

But once it is docked, *how to undock it?* Dragging its tab back doesn't help, after releasing the mouse button it always returns to the dock.

*Note:*

I know that I may make all dialogs floating in Preferences and then restart Inkscape, but it is not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would just drag the tab away from the dock, but in some recent versions of Inkscape on Windows you actually need to drag it all the way out of the window. [This is a known issue](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/2216).

As an alternative, you can just right-click the tab (or click the arrow pointing down next to the tabs in version 1.2) and select 'Move Tab to New Window'.